# Changing values inside my devexpree GridView on load

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I have a devexpress GridView that gets populated with data from a SQL database, very easy. Now i want to replace values in my one column.

If c04_oprogrs value is a 1 then display **Take** in the GridView.

If c04_oprogrs value is 2 then display **Available** in the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

While binding, you can use like this:

```
<dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" ID="lblWork" Text='<%# Convert.ToString(c04_oprogrs) == "1" ? "Take" : Convert.ToString(c04_oprogrs) == "2"  ? "Available" %>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.
1. use OnHtmlDataCellPrepared Event. for example:

```
protected void gridview1_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataColumn.FieldName == "c04_oprogrs")
        {
            if (e.CellValue != null)
                if (e.CellValue.ToString()=="1")
                {

                    e.Cell.Text = "Take ";
                }

        if (e.CellValue.ToString()=="2")
                {

                    e.Cell.Text = "Available ";
                }        
         }
    }
```

2. in biding

   ```
   <dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" ID="lable1" Text='<%# Eval("c04_oprogrs").ToString() == "1" ? "Take" : Eval("c04_oprogrs").ToString() == "2"  ? "Available" %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
         </DataItemTemplate>
   </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To display a custom cell text, handle the [CustomColumnDisplayText](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q386298/gridview-how-to-display-a-custom-cell-text) event instead.

**Example:**

```
protected void ASPxGridView2_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender,
    DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Column.FieldName != "UnitsOnOrder") return;
    if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Value) == 0)
        e.DisplayText = "empty";
}
```

**References:**
[How to: Provide Custom Display Text for Data Cells](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/3766/ASP-NET-WebForms-Controls/Grid-View/Examples/How-to-Provide-Custom-Display-Text-for-Data-Cells)